# onActivityResult for killed activity

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

can you help me with good solution for my problem.

I have Activity1, Activity2. 
Activity1 creates UI in `onCreate()`, then at some moment user starts Activity2 with `startActivityForResult()`

It seems out-of-memory situation to be very uncommon, but I faced it once, so I want to prevent it in future. I even can repeat this situation by running some "hard" app or game. The result is - when I return to my app Activity2 is recreated. And when I then return to Activity1 pressing Back button it is recreated too. And I have logical collision here. Activity1 UI is created from zero in `onCreate` and at the same time it is updated in `onActivityResult`!

How can I solve this? Trigger some flag in `onCreate` and check it in `onActivityResult`? This works for me, but I think it's not as it should be.

My phone has Stock ROM, Android 2.3.5

**UPDATE:** Ok, specific question, I have a list of elements. It is built in `onCreate()`. Leaving to Activity2 I need to remember id of element being clicked in order to update it later in `onActivityResult()`. It's not a problem to save it in bundle in `onSaveInstanceState()`. But! It's bad idea to get it from bundle in `onCreate()` because I have nothing to update! To make it clear here is pseudocode:

```
onCreate()
{
     elementId = getIdFromBundle();
     if (elementId == null) 
         createNewListFromZero();
}

onSaveInstanceState()
{
     putIdToBundle(elementId);
}

onActivityResult()
{
     updateOnlyOneListElement(elementId);
}
```

So I can't update element by it's id because activity actually was destroyed by system. And I need to rebuild it. And I have consecutive calls to `onCreate(), onActivityResult()`. The question is how should I share logic between these 2 methods to create\update my element list in right order?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing same issue!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at saving the activity state in the `onSaveInstanceState`. This bundled will be returned in the onCreate when the activity restarts.
Take a look at the lifecycle of the Activity

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Activity class javadoc:

*Note the "Killable" column in the above table -- for those methods that are marked as being killable, after that method returns the process hosting the activity may killed by the system at any time without another line of its code being executed. Because of this, you should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such as user edits) to storage.*

`In addition, the method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be re-created`